# async await promise all versus storing in a variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I was looking at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) for async await and found that there is an alternative to promise.all

so,

if `coffee` , `tea` and `description` are three promises we can await them all

```
let values = await Promise.all([coffee, tea, description]);
```

But the MDN also gives example of slow and fast async await:

Example of slow async await:

```
async function timeTest() {
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
}
```

Example of fast async await:

```
async function timeTest() {
  const timeoutPromise1 = timeoutPromise(3000);
  const timeoutPromise2 = timeoutPromise(3000);
  const timeoutPromise3 = timeoutPromise(3000);

  await timeoutPromise1;
  await timeoutPromise2;
  await timeoutPromise3;
}
```

I am confused about fast async await. Does it work similar to `promise.all()`? Is it better than `promise.all()?`

If we are writing multitple awaits in different lines how is it any different from slow async await?

Comment: "*Does it work similar to promise.all()?*" basically for simpler scenarios - yes. "*Is it better than promise.all()?*" define "better".

Comment: `Promise.all` is good if you don't know how many promises you need to wait for. What is "slow async await"?

Comment: The advantage of the "fast" method is it runs the processes in parallel, whereas the "slow" method runs them in series. `Promise.all` also runs then in parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This snippet:

```
async function timeTest() {
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
}
```

will initialize each Promise only after the last has completed.

- Initialize first Promise
- Wait for it to finish (3 seconds)
- Initialize second Promise (...etc)

In contrast, this snippet:

```
async function timeTest() {
  const timeoutPromise1 = timeoutPromise(3000);
  const timeoutPromise2 = timeoutPromise(3000);
  const timeoutPromise3 = timeoutPromise(3000);

  await timeoutPromise1;
  await timeoutPromise2;
  await timeoutPromise3;
}
```

will initialize all promises at once. Then, it'll

- wait for the first Promise to resolve
- wait for the second Promise to resolve
- wait for the third Promise to resolve

But the second snippet has a serious deficiency: if one of the promises happens to reject, it may result in an unhandled rejection despite there being an `await` before it. This could happen if, for example, `timeoutPromise1` has not resolved yet, and `timeoutPromise2` rejects:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', () => {
  console.error('Unhandled rejection :(');
});

async function timeTest() {
  const timeoutPromise1 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  const timeoutPromise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 500));
  
  await timeoutPromise1;
  await timeoutPromise2;
}

timeTest()
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error caught');
  });
```

This problem occurs because a Promise must be being `await`ed or have a `.catch` chained onto it *at the point at which it rejects*. If it rejects *before* a `.catch` or `await` is connected to it, an unhandled rejection will result.

Unhandled rejections, just like unhandled errors, are ugly and should be avoided. In Node, unhandled rejections aren't just *bad*, they're also deprecated, and can crash the Node process entirely.

So, using `Promise.all` is a better approach than your second snippet.

Comment: Also noteworthy is 'the function in a promise executes as soon as the promise is initialized and await means that subsequent lines in the same scope will not run until the promise awaited is resolved or rejected'...

Comment: Since you said it will initialize all promises at once and wait for each line, you are saying it is does not run in parallel as other answers suggests?

Comment: @SeyiShoboyejo Okay that explains a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @goxarad784 The Promises are initialized at once, so they all run in parallel, but their resolutions are waited for in serial. If none reject, it'll be the same as `Promise.all`.